# How to detect multiple/Overlapping GameObjects with the EventSystem?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I try to achieve: Toothbrush should show up wherever the user clicks inside `BoxCollider` `A`, including space inside `BoxCollider` `B`. But apparently clicking inside `B` will not show the toothbrush (OnPointerDown is not being triggered).

What I have tried: Changing the order of the layers.

Toothbrush is showed after user clicks inside box collider `A`, but if the user clicks inside box collider `B`- the toothbrush will not show up, which means `OnPointerDown` is not triggered.

I think it is because of the overlapping of one `BoxCollider2D` inside another `BoxCollider2D`. In my case `B` inside `A`, I assume that is the culprit, but I have no idea how to solve it or if maybe there is another method to implement `OnPointerDown`?

I am using `Perspective` camera. but in this scene all elements are in same `z position` which is 0. Is it possible to trigger IPointerHander event in every respective `BoxCollider2D` ?

[image]

#### DragableObject.cs

This script is attached to the toothbrush. The `BoxCollider2D` A also belongs to toothbrush.

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("pointer down");

    if (GetComponent<DragableObject>() == null)
        return;

    currentObject = GetComponent<DragableObject>();

    MeshRenderer renderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

    if (ShowOnTouch)
        ShowObject();

    // Store original state
    originalPosition = transform.position;
    originalOrderLayer = renderer.sortingOrder;
    // Snap to mouse
    Vector3 newPos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 30));
    newPos.z = 30;
    transform.position = newPos;

    if (BringToFront)
    {
        if (renderer != null)
        {
            renderer.sortingOrder = 90;
        }
    }

    ObjectActive.Invoke();
}
```

#### TargetListener.cs

This script is attached to `BoxCollider2D` B.

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Affectors.Count; i++) 
    {
        if (Affectors [i] == DragableObject.currentObject)
        {
            DragableObject.currentObject.OnEnterTarget(transform);

            ITriggerEffect[] iTrigger = GetComponents<ITriggerEffect>();

            for (int j = 0; j < iTrigger.Length; j++) 
            {
                Debug.Log("iTrigger enter");
                Debug.Log(iTrigger [j]);
                iTrigger [j].Execute(eventData, PointerState.Down);
            }
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

If i click on `A` the toothbrush will show up, except when i click inside `B`. Here the debug log.

[image]

This is the `BoxCollider2D` A is attached to, which is the `*Toothbrush` itself together with the `dragable.cs` script.

[image]

---

UPDATE: Thanks to others who answers, the problem become more clearer for me. Below is `BoxCollider2D` A and `BoxCollider2D` B. Both of them have script that have most of `OnPointerHander`. How do i make sure that all `OnPointerHandler` is triggered on respective `BoxCollider2D` ?.

[image]

Issues that i am having :

1. OnPointerExit on `A` is triggered when my pointer enter `B`.
2. if click inside `B` ,`OnPointerDown` only triggered on `B` but not `A`

Comment: Add the code you have in the OnTriggerEnter for both cases

Comment: sure,  gimme sec

Comment: Well try my answer, maybe it is not necessary that you add any script.

Comment: Put `Debug.Log` in the OnPointerDown code that is attached to `BoxCollider2D B` and lets us know if that's being called. If possible disable other colliders except for `BoxCollider2D B` and see if the problem is still there. This is how to troubleshoot and help people solve your issue otherwise you will be getting random answers.

Comment: In summary, what i try to achieve here is, to have overlapping `BoxCollider2D` while to make sure that all `PointerHander` is triggered on each of respective `BoxCollider2D`. is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, but it is **complicated**. I will leave an answer on how to do this

Comment: Before I put answer, just trying to be sure. When you said *"all PointerHander is triggered on each of respective BoxCollider2D"*, you want the objects behind objects where the mouse cursor is to also receive events?

Comment: @Programmer I think yes, I already updated my question, I need to show some visual because I am afraid my english lead to misunderstanding.

Comment: Ok. That's what I thought. Your English is good. It's just that your problem is complicated. Check back in a moment. Just testing this before posting.

Comment: @Programmer and Tengku. And isn't it easier (and with the same result) to use Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) instead the OnPointerDown(), and check with a raycast what colliders was hit?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre Let say if its work, for `OnPointerDown` is similar to `Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)`, but how to implement the other handler like `OnPointerEnter', `OnPointerExit`, ?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre EventSystem/OnPointerDown should be used if possible. It's a new feature that makes it possible to write one code that works on Desktop and mobile devices instead of having to write multiple code for each one. Also, you shouldn't be using GetMouseButtonDown on mobile devices. See my first answer for how I used pre-processor to separate mobile and desktop input then see my second answer for how one code with EventSystem will work on any platform. Yes, it complicated with EventSystem but that's because it's not  specifically  designed to do whar OP is asking but it can.

Comment: @Programmer I understand. Thanks for the information

Comment: @Tengku Check my answer for two ways to do this. I suggest you go with my **second** solution unless there is a problem with it.

Comment: @Programmer Since i use dragable.cs script on few working scene before. I need to test your script with new empty scene because i'm afraid it will create problem to other scene due to different structure. Until i totally understand with your code below. Thanks, i will give a try.

Comment: No problem. It is right to experiment on a new scene. All it does is detect an event then use the current mouse possible to perform an EventSystem raycast on each object the mouse pointer is over then manually triggers OnPointerDown on all of them.

Comment: I see, does it work for `OnPointerEnter` and other handler too ? because there is few thing in your code i never use before. so need to figure out so i am able to tweak if its working.

Comment: The title and body of your question says, you need it to work for `OnPointerDown` so it works with this only. The code is heavily commented and can be easily modified to work with other events if you read the comments.  If you can't modify it, create a new question with this code and I will leave a new solution that works on any event.

Comment: @Programmer I already try your script it working well, then i try to implement for other IPointer but TBH i have no idea how to do it. Because the case is different as IPointerDown. Here i open another question for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274674/how-to-make-ipointer-work-on-respective-box-collider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the good and advantages of the EventSystem is that events don't go through GameObjects. The first one that is hit is returned. Although, it looks like you don't want that. It complicated to make EventSystem return multiple GameObjects,

There two solutions for you:

**1**.Get ride of `EventSystem` (`OnPointerDown` and `IPointerDownHandler`)  and use the old school raycast system.

`Physics2D.RaycastAll` and `Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc` can do this. This example will use `RaycastNonAlloc` for performance reasons. It's very easy.

**Attach to only one GameObject(empty GameObject)**:

```
public class HitAll : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Detect up to 100 Objects
    const int raycastAmount = 100;
    RaycastHit2D[] result = new RaycastHit2D[raycastAmount];

    void Update()
    {
        #if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            checkRaycast(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        }
        #else
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            checkRaycast(Input.mousePosition);
        }
        #endif
    }

    void checkRaycast(Vector2 mousePos)
    {
        Vector3 origin = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        int hitCount = Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc(origin, Vector2.zero, result, 200);
        Debug.Log(hitCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Hit: " + result[i].collider.gameObject.name);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**2**.Continue using `EventSystem` but rethrow the event.

First, you throw raycast with `EventSystem.current.RaycastAll` then you manually invoke the event with `ExecuteEvents.Execute`.

**Attach to all the GameObject with 2D Collider and make sure that `Physics2DRaycaster` is attached to the camera**:

```
public class ThroughEventScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        rethrowRaycast(eventData, eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject);

        //DO STUFF WITH THE OBJECT HIT BELOW
        Debug.Log("Hit: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);
    }

    void rethrowRaycast(PointerEventData eventData, GameObject excludeGameObject)
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

        pointerEventData.position = eventData.pressPosition;
        //pointerEventData.position = eventData.position;}

        //Where to store Raycast Result
        List<RaycastResult> raycastResult = new List<RaycastResult>();

        //Rethrow the raycast to include everything regardless of their Z position
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerEventData, raycastResult);

        //Debug.Log("Other GameObject hit");
        for (int i = 0; i < raycastResult.Count; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log(raycastResult[i].gameObject.name);

            //Don't Rethrow Raycayst for the first GameObject that is hit
            if (excludeGameObject != null && raycastResult[i].gameObject != excludeGameObject)
            {
                //Re-simulate OnPointerDown on every Object hit
                simulateCallbackFunction(raycastResult[i].gameObject);
            }
        }
    }

    //This causes functions such as OnPointerDown to be called again
    void simulateCallbackFunction(GameObject target)
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        //pointerEventData.ra
        RaycastResult res = new RaycastResult();
        res.gameObject = target;
        pointerEventData.pointerCurrentRaycast = res;
        ExecuteEvents.Execute(target, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the intended functionality here? I'm suspecting that you want the toothbrush to display anytime a user clicks within the mouth space?

1. If so, then one fun way to fix this would be to adjust the ordering of the 'B' objects to be above the 'A' object in the Hierarchy so that they overlay the A collision area. This in turn will allow their interaction to block the interaction of the area defined underneath the collision area define by each 'B' collider.

   What we're doing with this methodology is forcing the OnPointerDown event to occur with the 'B' collider before it has a chance to collide with the 'A' collider.

Let me know if that makes sense and feel free to ask follow up questions about the method.

Still not sure if your case is what I think it is, but here's a video of the method i mentioned: [Demo Video](https://youtu.be/y7S8nAbEB00)

Comment: The toothbrush should be display wherever user click inside BoxCollider `A` including BoxCollider `B`, but toothbrush not showing up(OnPointerDown not triggered) if user click inside BoxCollider `B`. Eventually i tried above trick too by changing order layer but it still not working. Thanks.

Comment: I gotcha. If you are layering the buttons (you are using a ui canvas with buttons right?) correctly, then the clicks should be registered if the script has been added to both the `A` and `B` objects. Is that definitely not working?

Comment: Im afraid not, the toothbrush show/hide(OnPointerDown/OnPointerUp) is on `dragable.cs` script to control it. it will show `if user click inside `BoxCollider2D` A, it works except when the user click inside `BoxCollider2D` B. Because both of `BoxCollider2D` A and B have OnPointerHandler. So i assume maybe thats the issue ?

Comment: I added a video to my answer as a demo for what I mean. In the end, it's an issue with the layering that is causing the collider of object `A` to be raycast first instead of the the collider of object `B`.

Comment: Thank for the vid, but what should i do if what i want is clicking box B to trigger both `OnPointerDown` which is `B` and also behind it, in this case `A` ? Does the implementation of OnPointerHandler support it ? or maybe i should use different method ?

Comment: You could put the code in your OnPointDown method in the script on `A` into a method and call that method by caching a reference to object `A` or by calling a find each time (which you don't usually want to be doing a lot, but in this case it should be fine) `GameObject.Find("Name of Object A").GetComponent<ScriptName>().MethodToCall()`

Comment: Ya I have OnPointDown on `A`, but it is not called if i click on `B`, because `B` also have OnPointDown, so its only trigger `B` and skip `A`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154301/discussion-between-ejsd1989-and-tengku).