# unity3d onMouseOver not called when sprite above it

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a tile based grid system where each tile has a box collider. These tiles make use of:

```
OnMouseOver()
```

Which calls correctly. However, if I have another sprite with a collider in the same position as the tile, it seems to block the tile being able to trigger OnMouseOver().

What is a good fix for this?

Comment: Don't use `OnMouseOver` Use `OnPointerEnter`. See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188071/how-to-detect-multiple-overlapping-gameobjects-with-the-eventsystem/46192131#46192131) for more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect multiple/Overlapping GameObjects with the EventSystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188071/how-to-detect-multiple-overlapping-gameobjects-with-the-eventsystem/46192131#46192131)

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 possible solutions, they dont use OnMouseOver though..

1. Use raycasting from the screen to the mouse position, in your FixedUpdate method (as its physics based). In the raycast you can define which layers should be collided with, this allows you to determine which objects are detected.
2. If it doesnt work yet, another solution could be to make an invisible object which constantly in its update method sets its position to be the mouse position, then add a collider to it and set the collider as a trigger so it can move freely. Give the object the tag "Cursor" and use OnTriggerEnter as the method instead of OnMouseClick.

Comment: Attaching a collider to the mouse is an interesting idea.  I wonder how that compares performance-wise to the raycasting solution.

I'd like to see Unity make OnMouseOver behave like people expect it to. It should bubble similar to how JavaScript works in a browser IMO.