# How to make IPointer work on respective box collider?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to implement `IPointerEnter`, `IPointerExit`, `IPointerDown` and `IPointerUp`.

All of them were working fine until they start overlapping.

My question is how do I make `IPointer...` to work on their respective collider?

`A` and `B` are `BoxCollider2D`, `B` is inside of `A`. Both of them have a script that has above `IPointer...` implemented. Below are the issues that I am having with this condition.

1. Upon clicking mouse down inside `B`, only 1 box will trigger the `IPointerDown`. (This is solved by this link) [How to detect multiple/Overlapping GameObjects with the EventSystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188071/how-to-detect-multiple-overlapping-gameobjects-with-the-eventsystem)
2. If my pointer (mouse) is inside of `A` and I move the pointer (mouse) to `B`, `A` will get triggered (`IPointerExit`). What I try to achieve is `A` `IPointerExit` should be triggered on it's respective collider.

If I enter A then 'IPointerEnter' A should be triggered and if enter `B`, `IPointerEnter` `B` should then be triggered.

[image]

Comment: Simply speaking, you cannot achieve what you want using built-in `IPointer...` mechanism. Your best bet would be to use `Raycast` and check each layer separately.

Comment: @m.rogalski raycast on a UI Object?

Comment: @Programmer This new Unity's event system works on [raycasting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/EventSystem.html) so  yes, the only way I see here is to distinguish which layer was hit by that ray and check if there's any layer "below".

Comment: Nvm. I noticed this is BoxCollider2D and extension of another question so raycast should work. As for using layer, you have to fiddle with adding any overlapping object to a layer then raycasing each one. That doesn't sound good. I would advice OP to stick with IPointerDown when detecting clicks on objects.

Comment: @OP When I have time, I will extend that to work with other pointer events 
 other than `IPointerDown` but if anyone can do that then they should.

Comment: @Programmer i managed to found the solution, but somehow it is not really stable when have complicated overlapping box, i spends days to figure out. and i think its a unity bug. because sometime it work sometime not.

Comment: I made a solution yesterday but didn't post it because it has something I consider to be Unity bug too. It works sometimes. I did not use enum like you did. I used generic `ExecuteEvents.EventFunction<T>` which made it easier and cleaner. See it [here](https://codeshare.io/2j8kRL)

Comment: I try your code too, but did not spot which bug you talking about. anyway it only work for down/up/click but not for enter/exit. my answer below work for enter/exit, but somehow, there is a bug where pointerup sometime not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to create a script for above issue, It works for simple overlapping. which means any `BoxCollider2D` that need to be inside another box must be the most top order layer. Just extend `OverlapEventTrigger`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TFTM.Event
{
    public enum EventExecuteType
    {
        PointerEnter,
        PointerExit,
        PointerDown,
        PointerUp,
        PointerDrag,
    }

    public abstract class OverlapEventTrigger : EventTrigger, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler, IDragHandler
    {
    public virtual void MouseDown(PointerEventData eventData){}
    public virtual void MouseUp(PointerEventData eventData){}
    public virtual void MouseEnter(PointerEventData eventData){}
    public virtual void MouseExit(PointerEventData eventData){}
    public virtual void MouseDrag(PointerEventData eventData){}

    List<GameObject> ObjectsInCollider = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<RaycastResult> lastTotalRaycastResult = new List<RaycastResult>();

    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Down: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);

        MouseDown(eventData);

        rethrowRaycast(eventData, eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject, EventExecuteType.PointerDown);
    }

    public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Up: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);

        MouseUp(eventData);

        rethrowRaycast(eventData, eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject, EventExecuteType.PointerUp);
    }

    public override void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (IsPointerInsideCollider(eventData) && ObjectsInCollider.Contains(gameObject))
            return;

        Debug.Log("Enter: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);

        MouseEnter(eventData);

        ObjectsInCollider.Add(gameObject);
    }

    public override void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Is " + gameObject.name + " inside his respective collider : " + IsPointerInsideCollider(eventData));

        if (IsPointerInsideCollider(eventData))
            return;

        Debug.Log("Exit: " + gameObject.name);

        MouseExit(eventData);

        ObjectsInCollider.Remove(gameObject);
    }

    public override void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Debug.Log("Drag: " + eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject.name);

        MouseDrag(eventData);

        rethrowRaycast(eventData, eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.gameObject, EventExecuteType.PointerDrag);
    }

    bool IsPointerInsideCollider(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        pointerEventData.position = eventData.position;

        List<RaycastResult> raycastResult = new List<RaycastResult>();

        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerEventData, raycastResult);

        for (int i = 0; i < raycastResult.Count; i++)
        {
            if (raycastResult[i].gameObject == gameObject)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    void rethrowRaycast(PointerEventData eventData, GameObject excludeGameObject, EventExecuteType eventType)
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);

        pointerEventData.position = eventData.pressPosition;
        //pointerEventData.position = eventData

        //Where to store Raycast Result
        List<RaycastResult> raycastResult = new List<RaycastResult>();

        //Rethrow the raycast to include everything regardless of their Z position
        EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(pointerEventData, raycastResult);

        //Debug.Log("Other GameObject hit");
        for (int i = 0; i < raycastResult.Count; i++)
        {
            //Debug.Log(raycastResult[i].gameObject.name);

            //Don't Rethrow Raycayst for the first GameObject that is hit
            if (excludeGameObject != null && raycastResult[i].gameObject != excludeGameObject || eventType == EventExecuteType.PointerDrag)
            {
                //Re-simulate OnPointerDown on every Object hit
                simulateCallbackFunction(raycastResult[i].gameObject, eventType);
            }
        }
    }

    //This causes functions such as OnPointerDown to be called again
    void simulateCallbackFunction(GameObject target, EventExecuteType eventType)
    {
        PointerEventData pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
        //pointerEventData.ra
        RaycastResult res = new RaycastResult();
        res.gameObject = target;
        pointerEventData.pointerCurrentRaycast = res;
        pointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;

        switch (eventType) {
            case EventExecuteType.PointerDown:
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(target, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
                break;
            case EventExecuteType.PointerUp:
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(target, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.pointerUpHandler);
                break;
            case EventExecuteType.PointerDrag:
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(target, pointerEventData, ExecuteEvents.dragHandler);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }


}
```